# sigemptyset() NDK UnsatisfiedLinkError dlopen()

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, libc

A certain C-code in my Android NDK application, calls the `sigemptyset()` function defined in the signal.h. I am building my project using the `NDK-r9`.

My library file called *"libnative-service.so"* is built fine, after the c-code is compiled. 
But on running the application i get the following error regarding the refernce to `sigemptyset()`.

Am i missing something ??

```
09-22 15:13:09.102: E/art(3718): dlopen("/data/app-lib/com.project/libnative-service.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "sigemptyset" referenced by "libnative-service.so"...
09-22 15:13:09.103: D/AndroidRuntime(3718): Shutting down VM
09-22 15:13:09.106: E/AndroidRuntime(3718): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-22 15:13:09.106: E/AndroidRuntime(3718): Process: com.project, PID: 3718
09-22 15:13:09.106: E/AndroidRuntime(3718): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "sigemptyset" referenced by "libnative-service.so"...
```

Comment: How are you compiling/building your library?  What's the compiler/linker command line?

Comment: Did this work for you? Im also haveing a similar problem when tryng to run ndk profiling tool

Answer (score 2):

This function appears to be declared inline:

```
static __inline__ int sigemptyset(sigset_t *set)
{
    memset(set, 0, sizeof *set);
    return 0;
}
```

So it should already be resolved in the compiled library, and not a dependency to be filled by runtime linking.  If it is unresolved, it would seem that your library has not built correctly.

Did you perhaps link against the wrong headers?  If you used a non-ndk signal.h you might not be compiling usage of this function correctly.

Comment: There seems to be no compiler errors. And I am also using these flags in my Android.mk file:
   LOCAL_LDLIBS += -ldl -llog -lc -lm

Comment: Not getting compiler errors *does not* mean that you have compiled correctly for an Android target - rather, the problem is that the compiler is *not* following the instructions in the ndk headers, perhaps because it isn't looking at those but rather at some *other* ones it was mistakenly pointed at.

Comment: My Android.mk file refrences a file in another project like this: 

include ../tun2socks/Android.mk .

I need to keep my C files in a seperate project. If i include all my C files in the same project then everything works fine