# Android ndk cannot find symbol "sigemptyset"

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I am building a C app for android, I use 'sigemptyset' in my app, when I compile the code using NDK it is compiled successfully, but when running the app I get `cannot locate symbol 'sigemptyset'`.

After searching I found that the problem is that I build the app using ndk-r11 which build for android-5 but I am running the app on android 4.4 where `sigemptyset` definition has changed. so I added the following to Android.mk:

```
TARGET_PLATFORM := android-19
```

but I still get the same error

Does anyone know how to fix this?

EDIT:

This question is not a duplicate of another question nor the answer there suggests changing the `APP_PLATFORM` parameter in Application.mk

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sigemptyset() NDK UnsatisfiedLinkError dlopen()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975291/sigemptyset-ndk-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dlopen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of problem is not the version of NDK that was used but version of target platform. `android-19` is the last platform version where `sigemptyset()` (and many other functions) was declared as inline just at platform headers. As result - system libc on that devices doesn't contain such functions. So you are right - you should use proper target platform to allow your code to run on older devices. But you are doing it incorrectly. All that you need is add

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
```

to your `Application.mk`.

Comment: I have found it already, but anyway thank you your answer is correct